# Is minutes watched time of a video available in youtube analytics api ?

Tags: youtube-api

I couldnt find from the documentation (https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/available_reports) if the **minutes watched** metric can be obtained from the **youtube analytics api**. If it can be retrieved can you give the endpoint to query as ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Timed watched is not a current metric provided by the api.

Answer (score 0):

Under v2 of the Analytics API there is a metric called `estimatedMinutesWatched` that can provide that information now. There's more info at developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/metrics